# How to pass a function as delegate and force the compiler to restrict only a function that belongs to a class that implements a specific interface

Tags: c#, .net, oop, delegates

I am working on a class that will have a multiple instances and different delegate function will be passed via the constructor for each object.

how can i pass a function as delegate to `MissionGenerator` class and
 force the compiler **(at design time)** to restrict only a function that belongs to a class that implements `IDelegateMission` interface.
 or maybe even better, if possible: belongs to class that implements `IDelegateMission` and from "type" `RaiseTask ()`.

please take a look at the code below, it shows quite clear what I wish to achive.

```
// delegate type for tasks
public delegate void TaskDelegate();

public class MissionGenerator
{
    protected TaskDelegate MissionToInvoke;

    public MissionGenerator(TaskDelegate mission)
    {
        this.MissionName = MissionName;
    }
}

interface IDelegateMission
{
    System.DayOfWeek ExecutionDay { get; set; }
    int HourOfExecution { get; set; }
    void RaiseTask();
}

class Skarim: IDelegateMission
{
    // class implement all IDelegateMission methods...
    public void RaiseTask()
    {
        // this is the function to pass as TaskDelegate...
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    private void MainMethod()
    {
         MissionGenerator sekerMission = new MissionGenerator(new Skarim().RaiseTask);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Pass `IDelegateMission` and call `RaiseTask` on it instead of passing delegate?

Comment: @Evk that makes sense.. maybe i will use your suggestion, need to check all constrains first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Evk's comment, do something like this:

```
public delegate void TaskDelegate();

public class MissionGenerator
{
    protected TaskDelegate MissionToInvoke;

    public MissionGenerator(IDelegateMission mission)
    {
        MissionToInvoke = mission.RaiseTask; 
    }

    public void StartMission() => MissionToInvoke();
}

public interface IDelegateMission
{
    void RaiseTask();
}

public class Skarim : IDelegateMission
{
    public void RaiseTask() => Debug.WriteLine("Yo.");
}

public class MainClass
{
    private void MainMethod()
    {
         var sekerMission = new MissionGenerator(new Skarim());
         sekerMission.StartMission();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you Colin and Evk. I will use that approach, but there is no need for the delegate, inside the class i will create a global variable of type `IDelegateMission` and i will use further more properties and methods of that interface.